# Problems building Qt Static 5.3.2

Tags: c++, qt, powershell, build, mingw-w64

So I am trying to build Qt-Static 5.3.2.  I am using a powershell script I downloaded to simplify the process but clearly it is not working.   I am going to be tackling each error individually for the rest of the day.  I am a beginner and I don't fully understand the build process so any bits of advice and insights is welcomed and appreciated.

I have posted the output on this dropbox link because it has 10X the characters that is allowed.
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/poge94qm1wzg5vg/Building%20static%20Qt%20version%205.3.2.docx?dl=0

```
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#  Copyright (c) 2013, Thierry Lelegard
#  All rights reserved.
# 
#  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
#  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
# 
#  1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
#     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
#  2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution. 
# 
#  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
#  AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
#  IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
#  ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
#  LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
#  CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
#  SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
#  INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
#  CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
#  ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF
#  THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
# 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

<#
 .SYNOPSIS

  Build a static version of Qt for Windows.

 .DESCRIPTION

  This scripts downloads Qt source code, compiles and installs a static version
  of Qt. It assumes that a prebuilt Qt / MinGW environment is already installed,
  typically in C:\Qt. This prebuilt environment uses shared libraries. It is
  supposed to remain the main development environment for Qt. This script adds
  a static version of the Qt libraries in order to allow the construction of
  standalone and self-sufficient executable.

  This script is typically run from the Windows Explorer.

  Requirements:
  - Windows PowerShell 3.0 or higher.
  - 7-zip.

 .PARAMETER QtSrcUrl

  URL of the Qt source file archive.
  By default, use the latest identified version.

 .PARAMETER QtStaticDir

  Root directory where the static versions of Qt are installed.
  By default, use C:\Qt\Static.

 .PARAMETER QtVersion

  The Qt version. By default, this script tries to extract the version number
  from the Qt source file name.

 .PARAMETER MingwDir

  Root directory of the MinGW prebuilt environment. By default, use the version
  which was installed by the prebuilt Qt environment.

 .PARAMETER NoPause

  Do not wait for the user to press <enter> at end of execution. By default,
  execute a "pause" instruction at the end of execution, which is useful
  when the script was run from Windows Explorer.
#>




[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $QtSrcUrl = "http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2.7z",
    $QtStaticDir = "C:\Qt\Static",
    $QtVersion = "5.3.2",
    $MingwDir = "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32",
    [switch]$NoPause = $false
)

# PowerShell execution policy.
Set-StrictMode -Version 3

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main code
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Main
{
    # Check that 7zip is installed. We use it to expand the downloaded archive.
    [void] (Get-7zip)

    # Get Qt source file name from URL.
    $QtSrcFileName = Split-Path -Leaf $QtSrcUrl

    # If Qt version is not specified on the command line, try to extract the value.
    if (-not $QtVersion) {
        $QtVersion = $QtSrcFileName -replace "`.[^`.]*$",''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'qt-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'everywhere-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'opensource-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'src-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace '-src',''
    }
    Write-Output "Building static Qt version $QtVersion"

    # Qt installation directory.
    $QtDir = "$QtStaticDir\$QtVersion"

    # Get MinGW root directory, if not specified on the command line.
    if (-not $MingwDir) {
        # Search all instances of gcc.exe from C:\Qt prebuilt environment.
        $GccList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Qt\*\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe | ForEach-Object FullName | Sort-Object)
        if ($GccList.Length -eq 0) {
            Exit-Script "MinGW environment not found, no Qt prebuilt version?"
        }
        $MingwDir = (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $GccList[$GccList.Length - 1]))
    }
    Write-Output "Using MinGW from $MingwDir"

    # Build the directory tree where the static version of Qt will be installed.
    Create-Directory $QtStaticDir\src
    Create-Directory $QtDir

    # Download the Qt source package if not yet done.
    Download-File $QtSrcUrl $QtStaticDir\src\$QtSrcFileName

    # Directory of expanded packages.
    $QtSrcDir = "$QtStaticDir\src\$((Get-Item $QtStaticDir\src\$QtSrcFileName).BaseName)"

    # Expand archives if not yet done
    Expand-Archive $QtStaticDir\src\$QtSrcFileName $QtStaticDir\src $QtSrcDir

    # Patch Qt's mkspecs for static build.
    $File = "$QtSrcDir\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf"
    if (-not (Select-String -Quiet -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive "# [QT-STATIC-PATCH]" $File)) {
        Write-Output "Patching $File ..."
        Copy-Item $File "$File.orig"
        @"

# [QT-STATIC-PATCH]
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static -static-libgcc -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable -auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc
QMAKE_LFLAGS_EXCEPTIONS_ON = -mthreads -Wl
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Os -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
DEFINES += QT_STATIC_BUILD
"@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
    }

    # Set a clean path including MinGW.
    $env:Path = "$MingwDir\bin;$MingwDir\opt\bin;$env:SystemRoot\system32;$env:SystemRoot"

    # Force English locale to avoid weird effects of tools localization.
    $env:LANG = "en"

    # Set environment variable QT_INSTALL_PREFIX. Documentation says it should be
    # used by configure as prefix but this does not seem to work. So, we will
    # also specify -prefix option in configure.
    $env:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX = $QtDir

    # Configure, compile and install Qt.
    Push-Location $QtSrcDir
    cmd /c "configure.bat -static -release -platform win32-g++ -prefix $QtDir `
        -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl `
        -opensource -confirm-license `
        -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests"
    mingw32-make -k -j4
    mingw32-make -k install
    Pop-Location

    # Patch Qt's installed mkspecs for static build of application.
    $File = "$QtDir\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf"
    @"
CONFIG += static
"@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii

    Exit-Script
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# A function to exit this script. The Message parameter is used on error.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Exit-Script ([string]$Message = "")
{
    $Code = 0
    if ($Message -ne "") {
        Write-Output "ERROR: $Message"
        $Code = 1
    }
    if (-not $NoPause) {
        pause
    }
    exit $Code
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Silently create a directory.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Create-Directory ([string]$Directory)
{
    [void] (New-Item -Path $Directory -ItemType "directory" -Force)
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Download a file if not yet present.
# Warning: If file is present but incomplete, do not download it again.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Download-File ([string]$Url, [string]$OutputFile)
{
    $FileName = Split-Path $Url -Leaf
    if (-not (Test-Path $OutputFile)) {
        # Local file not present, start download.
        Write-Output "Downloading $Url ..."
        try {
            $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
            $webclient.DownloadFile($Url, $OutputFile)
        }
        catch {
            # Display exception.
            $_
            # Delete partial file, if any.
            if (Test-Path $OutputFile) {
                Remove-Item -Force $OutputFile
            }
            # Abort
            Exit-Script "Error downloading $FileName"
        }
        # Check that the file is present.
        if (-not (Test-Path $OutputFile)) {
            Exit-Script "Error downloading $FileName"
        }
    }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get path name of 7zip, abort if not found.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Get-7zip
{
    $Exe = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    if (-not (Test-Path $Exe)) {
        $Exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    }
    if (-not (Test-Path $Exe)) {
        Exit-Script "7-zip not found, install it first, see http://www.7-zip.org/"
    }
    $Exe
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expand an archive file if not yet done.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Expand-Archive ([string]$ZipFile, [string]$OutDir, [string]$CheckFile)
{
    # Check presence of expected expanded file or directory.
    if (-not (Test-Path $CheckFile)) {
        Write-Output "Expanding $ZipFile ..."
        & (Get-7zip) x $ZipFile "-o$OutDir" | Select-String -Pattern "^Extracting " -CaseSensitive -NotMatch
        if (-not (Test-Path $CheckFile)) {
            Exit-Script "Error expanding $ZipFile, $OutDir\$CheckFile not found"
        }
    }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Execute main code.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. Main
```

Comment: What does C:\QtBuild>where moc is telling you? Like:
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\bin\moc.exe I wonder if you can execute moc.exe in your path. If you don't have where command available check if standard path is there and you able to execute it.

Comment: I apologize, I am a beginner and have spent the last two hours basically understanding the basics behind qmake and makefiles.   I found the file. executed it but all I see is a command line interface.  I read up on moc.exe and it creates meta-object code for source files with the Q_Object Macro.  How does that tie into building Qt Static?

Comment: Moc is Qt metacompiler. On Windows it is moc.exe. I wonder if it is in the path as long as the output provided implies some problem with moc files. I could have be wrong but there is such problem there. Building Qt static involves quite a few important details but it takes effort to understand what went wrong on your system. I only found some apparent trouble there.

Comment: Alright, so specifically, what path are you referring to?  If you are referring to C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\bin\moc.exe, it is there.

Comment: can you pinpoint were the trouble was in the ouput file.  Also I am beginning to see that it seems like alot of people have had to apply a couple of patches to get this working

Comment: Look for "error" in your build output: "[.moc/release/moc_qabstractanimation.cpp] Error 1976996241" You have to have moc.exe in the executable path to start with.